# Calculus- Conceptual question about velocity.

Tags: calculus

So I was working on a problem from the book Kline calculus and stumbled upon the following problem:

> A bullet is shot straight up and returns to earth in 20 seconds. What is the initial speed?

I got the answer but still wanted to look at the solution. In the solution it proposed two ways of doing this either setting $s(t)=0$ when $t=20$ or setting $v(10)=0$.  I understand the first equation but I am unsure about the second one.

I thought to myself that setting $v(10)=0$ is assuming that the bullet took $10$ seconds to go up and $10$ seconds to go down. So I asked myself can the bullet take for example $6$ seconds to go up and $4$ seconds to go down. For that to happen it would have to imply that velocity of the bullet follows one equation for the up motion and another for the down motion.

That got me thinking. If I have two different bullets and I shoot them at the same time both of them will have an acceleration of $-32$ feet/sec$^2$. Hence $v(t)$ for both bullets will be $-32t+C$. In consequence the only thing that can change is the $C$ or $V_0$.

Now if I decide that bullet one will have an initial velocity of $144$ feet/sec and that the second bullet will have a $V_0$ of $200$ feet/sec would't that affect the time it gets to get the maximum height. I.E maximum height will be reached when $t= 4.5$ s for the first bullet WHILE the maximum height will be  reached when $t= 6.5$ s for the second bullet.

My question is how could that be? If my second bullet has a bigger $V_0$ shouldn't it reach the top in less time then my first bullet ?

Comment: This does not really change the point of the question, but at an initial upward velocity of $200$ ft/sec and a gravitational acceleration of $32$ ft/sec/sec downward, the second bullet will take $6.25$ seconds, not $6.5$ seconds, to reach the top of its arc.

Comment: Yeah sorry my calculation did give me 6.25 I guess I just missed the 2.

Answer (score 1):

The top of the arc of the bullet initially traveling $144$ ft/sec
is $324$ feet (assuming gravitational acceleration is $32$ ft/sec/sec).
The top of the arc of the bullet initially traveling $200$ ft/sec
is $625$ feet.

So yes, the second bullet is (at least initially) traveling toward
"the top" faster than the first bullet, but "the top" for the second
bullet is a lot farther away. The increase in distance to the top is so large
that it more than compensates for the increase in initial velocity.

Comment: Ok yeah thanks I get what you're saying.